# How do I make the Turtle drawing speed faster?

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

How can I make the Python library Turtle, run and draw a square in 1 screen tick?

```
import turtle as t
import math

def square():
  t.penup()
  t.goto(cord_x_1, cord_y_1)
  t.pendown()
  t.goto(cord_x_2, cord_y_2)
  t.goto(cord_x_3, cord_y_3)
  t.goto(cord_x_4, cord_y_4)
  t.goto(cord_x_1, cord_y_1)
  t.penup()
 
t.speed(0)
theta = 0

print("What do you want for angle Θ?")
radians_theta = math.fmod(float(theta), 360)
sqrt =  math.sqrt((50)**2+(50)**2)

while 2 > 1: 
  radians_theta = math.fmod(float(theta), 360)

  #cord setup
  cord_x_1 = sqrt * math.cos(radians_theta)
  cord_y_1 = sqrt * math.sin(radians_theta)

  cord_x_2 = sqrt * math.cos(radians_theta + math.radians(90))
  cord_y_2 = sqrt * math.sin(radians_theta + math.radians(90))

  cord_x_3 = sqrt * math.cos(radians_theta + math.radians(180))
  cord_y_3 = sqrt * math.sin(radians_theta + math.radians(180))

  cord_x_4 = sqrt * math.cos(radians_theta + math.radians(270))
  cord_y_4 = sqrt * math.sin(radians_theta + math.radians(270))

  #repeat
  t.clear()
  square()
  theta += 30
  theta = theta % 360
  print(theta)
```

What I'm wanting is to have the turtle draw the rotated square very fast. I tried setting the speed to 0, but that is not fast enough. Does anyone know how I could speed turtle up?

Comment: If you are trying to draw graphics really fast, then turtle may not be the best library to use.

Comment: Michael, what would be a better library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly. Sometimes the turtle speed is not fast enough and so there is a way to go even faster. The way would be to disable the [animation entirely](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.tracer).
`t.tracer(0)` will disable animation.So put this somewhere near the top of your code. Now at the end of your code you will need `t.update()` to force an update once the turtle is finished and show it on screen.

Answer (score 0):

We can probably beat simply adding `tracer()` and `update()` by also precomputing the fixed set of images that get drawn:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle, Vec2D
from math import sin, cos, radians, sqrt
from itertools import cycle

def square(cord_1, cord_2, cord_3, cord_4):
    turtle.goto(cord_1)

    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.goto(cord_2)
    turtle.goto(cord_3)
    turtle.goto(cord_4)
    turtle.goto(cord_1)
    turtle.penup()

def draw():
    theta, cord_1, cord_2, cord_3, cord_4 = next(endless_coordinates)
    turtle.clear()
    square(cord_1, cord_2, cord_3, cord_4)
    screen.update()
    print(theta)
    screen.ontimer(draw)

theta = 0
delta = 30
diagonal = sqrt(2 * 50**2)
coordinates = []

for theta in range(0, 360, delta):
    theta_radians = radians(theta)

    cord_1 = diagonal * Vec2D(cos(theta_radians), sin(theta_radians))
    cord_2 = diagonal * Vec2D(cos(theta_radians + radians(90)), sin(theta_radians + radians(90)))
    cord_3 = diagonal * Vec2D(cos(theta_radians + radians(180)), sin(theta_radians + radians(180)))
    cord_4 = diagonal * Vec2D(cos(theta_radians + radians(270)), sin(theta_radians + radians(270)))

    coordinates.append((theta, cord_1, cord_2, cord_3, cord_4))

endless_coordinates = cycle(coordinates)

screen = Screen()
screen.tracer(False)

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.hideturtle()
turtle.penup()

draw()

screen.exitonclick()
```

We can also eliminate turtle-level drawing by spinning the turtle itself, pushing all the drawing down to the **C**-level:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

SQUARE_SIZE = 100
DELTA = 30

CURSOR_SIZE = 20

theta = 0

def draw():
    global theta

    turtle.left(DELTA)
    screen.update()

    theta = (theta + DELTA) % 360
    print(theta)

    screen.ontimer(draw)

screen = Screen()
screen.tracer(False)

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.shape('square')
turtle.fillcolor('white')
turtle.shapesize(SQUARE_SIZE / CURSOR_SIZE)
turtle.penup()

draw()

screen.exitonclick()
```